# /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Permission denied in Linux

Tags: php, linux, wkhtmltopdf, permission-denied

I read nearly all topics concerning `wkhtmltopdf`, but my problem still exists. Actually it's not a `wkhtmltopdf` problem, but a permission problem.

To sum it up: `wkhtmltopdf` works in the command line, but not with PHP `exec()`.

But wget works fine with php exec():

I can execute wkhtmltopdf in the command line, works fine:

> /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf "test.html" "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf"

```
exec( "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --enable-plugins --encoding UTF-8 --javascript-delay 2000 --load-error-handling ignore --disable-smart-shrinking --image-quality 100 --orientation Portrait --minimum-font-size 10 --header-spacing '0' --margin-top '15mm' --header-html '/tmp/1568618584_generated.html' --footer-left 'Accume Partners Risk Director' --footer-right 'Residual Risk Report -- Page [page] of [toPage]' --footer-font-size '8' --footer-line /tmp/1568618584_generated.html /tmp/R_RM_2110_Residual_Risk_Report.pdf 2>&1", $output, $pdfGenerateStatus);

    print_r($output).'<br>'; 
    echo $pdfGenerateStatus;
```

it's return Array

> ( [0] => sh: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Permission denied ) 126 error.

I am using `wkhtmltopdf` 0.12.4 (with patched qt).
Also,

> I have set 777 permission to /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf but did not work.

Comment: Check it with `sudo -u www /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf "test.html" "/var/www/html/test/test.pdf"` to check if  the www user have the permission to run wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: You need to make sure you server user for example www has the permission to access the full path of the command,source file, and destination file.

Comment: chmod +X usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf ...and check chown?